# Partitions of a given set of first $n$ natural numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $n$ and $t$ be given natural numbers with $t\leq n$. Consider the set $S=\{1,2,...,n\}$.

**1.** Can we partition the set $S$ in to non empty subsets $S_1$, $S_2$, $S_3$,...,$S_t$ of equal size such that sum of elements in each set is equal?
$\left( For\  example\  when\  n=4\ and\ t=2\ then\ we\ can\ take\ S_1= \{1,4\}\ and\  S_2=\{2,3\}\ so\ that\ sum\ of\ elements\ in\ both\ the\ sets\ is\ 5 \right)$

**2.** If such a partition is impossible then what are the conditions on $n$ and $t$?

**3.** If the partition is possible then what are the conditions on $n$ and $t$?

**4.** When it is possible, how to construct such subsets $S_i's$?

Comment: Trivially, a partition always exists when $n$ is even and $t = n$. Take $S_{i} = \left\{i, n − i\right\}$ for all $i = 1, 2, \dots, n - 1$. The common sum of these sets is $n$.

Comment: Ahh yes. You are certainly right. That should be $t = \frac{n}{2}$. :)

Comment: Check this paper on Arxiv: https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.6916